# How to change transmission range for specific nodes mixim (omnet++)

Tags: omnet++

I am using mixim and built a network including 10 nodes based on MAC 802.11.
I intend to change the transmission range of two nodes with Tx range = 200, and the other 8 nodes have Tx range = 300. I know to change Tx range of nodes, I should change Tx power in Phy layer and connection manager.
But, If I change the values, the transmission range of all the nodes will change because all the nodes use the same connection manager. Moreover, because all the nodes should have connections with others, I think I cannot use different connection managers.

In brief, I intend to change the Tx range of specific nodes (not all) in the network with same configuration, while all the nodes have connections together.

Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to set in the connection manager is the *maximum interference range* which has almost nothing to do with the range where radios are actually can successfully receive each other's packet. That seems to be only an *optimization* parameter. PhyLayer modules are present in each node, so those power parameters can be set independently for each, but you will have a HARD time figuring out, what power you should set, to get a specific distance (like 200m).

I advise you NOT to use MiXiM (and let it rest in peace), as it is a long abandoned project and all the functionality in it was merged long ago into the INET Framework.

In INET framework, you can set up UnitDisc radios, where you actually can set a transmission range in meters.

Check the wireless tutorial: https://inet.omnetpp.org/docs/tutorials/wireless/doc/step3.html

Comment: I need to set different "maximum interference range" to two sets of nodes. Could you guide me on how can I set the change(s)?

Also,I really thank you for your suggestion about using INET. Actually, I am not a beginner in OMNET++. One of the biggest problems for me about using INET is the compiling time of the framework. If it will be possible to compile the codes/layers related to a project in the INET instead of compiling the whole of the codes/layers, I think it will be more user-friendly.